# Servlet request.getParameter() always returning “null”

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm trying to send parameter from text box in JSP to the servlet. 
For some reason I always get null when trying to get the parameter from the servlet.

My HTML code is :

```
<FORM method="POST" action="eimLoggingServlet">
        Execution Id <b><INPUT type="text" name="Execution_Id" size="10"> <INPUT
        type="submit" name="submit" value="Find log">
</FORM>
```

My Servlet Code is :

```
public class EimLoggingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {


            String exeId = request.getParameter("Execution_Id");


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }


}
```

And my Web.xml :

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>eimServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.viewlinks.eim.monitoring.servlet.EimLoggingServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>eimServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/eimLoggingServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

exeId is always null.

Comment: are you printing it in logs or console?

Comment: There are some IE bugs that can cause empty POST requests, especially when using "NTLM HTTP Single Sign-On (SSO) Authentication" on your website. Are you using that?

Comment: I'm not printing 'execId' I am using is for some other purposes but it is not relevent

Comment: I'm not using "NTLM HTTP Single Sign-On (SSO) Authentication" on my web Site.

Comment: Which browser have you used for your tests?

Comment: Is that really your actual form? Somehow I doubt it due to the `<b>` before input.

Comment: whats wrong with <b> ? it is just making " Execution Id" label bold

Comment: apparently when I run it in eclipse with tomcat it works , but when I deploy it to tomcat server as war , this error has accrues. Every thing is Ok , I can debug the Servlet but some how the request.getParameter("Execution_Id") always null

Answer (score 0):

I have Changed 'POST' to 'GET' and apparently the problem was solved:

JSP :

```
 <FORM method="GET" action="eimLoggingServlet">
        Execution Id <b><INPUT type="text" name="Execution_Id" size="10"> <INPUT
        type="submit" name="submit" value="Find log">
</FORM>
```

Servlet :

```
public class EimLoggingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {


            String exeId = request.getParameter("Execution_Id");


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }


}
```